# Send a link in an <a>m or something that has the same effect, in an XMPP message using Smack

Tags: java, xmpp, smack, pidgin

I'm using the pidgin xmpp client and I want to send from java a hyperlink, I have all the code necessary to send messages, but when it comes to sending a hyperlink the only format that I can successfully send from java seems to be the raw url:

```
http://abc.xyz
```

This works fine but what I want is something more like:

```
Alphabet
```

I've tried using `<a>` but that just comes out in the raw format again:

```
<a href="http://abc.xyz">Alphabet</a>
```

Edit:
I have written a client so I can read the raw format and it seems there are characters in the message that get escaped, notably `<` goes to `&lt;` and `>` goes to `&gt;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send HTML formatted IM messages over XMPP you need to use [`XHTML-IM`](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0071.html) to send your message.

Do that and pidgin should display it correctly.